# Cannot use SSH with OSMC Kodi

Tags: ssh, kodi, osmc, login

I've recently started using my Pi and I am running into a pretty annoying setback. I am trying to do a few things in headless mode and can't even get in with an SSH commands. The default user and password (osmc) haven't been changed, and when I first installed it onto the sd card I could get in, but now nothing works. I can connect using the http port, but that isn't useful for what I want to do. I'm considering just wiping it and starting over, since I haven't really done a lot on it yet that can't be done again. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just came back to this. It was so long ago that I don't remember the problem exactly, but I do remember having to reinstall an OS every time the pi restarted, sometimes more. That error was because the SD card was bad, and was causing several other issues as well. I don't know if that was the root cause in this case, but it was for sure the root of most of my other problems.

Lesson learned, don't go for whatever's laying around. Check [this list](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#Working_.2F_Non-working_SD_cards) if you're going to be getting a card.